# Random result on more threads in the Replicated Workers Paradigm

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized

My code is the following:

WorkPool.java

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

/**
 * Class that implements a work pool based on the model of "replicated workers"
 * Tasks introduced in the work pool are objects of type MRCTask
 *
 */
public class WorkPool {
    int nThreads; //total number of worker threads
    int nWaiting = 0; //number of worker threads blocked waiting for a task
    public boolean ready = false; //problem is finished 

    LinkedList<MRCTask> tasks = new LinkedList<MRCTask>();

    /**
     * Constructor for class WorkPool.
     * @param nThreads - number of worker threads
     */
    public WorkPool(int nThreads) {

        this.nThreads = nThreads;

    }

    /**
     * Function which tries to obtain a task from the work pool
     * If there are not available tasks, the function hangs until
     * a task can be given or until the problem is finished
     * @return A task to solve or null if the problem is finished
     */
    public synchronized MRCTask getWork() {

        if (tasks.size() == 0) { //empty work pool
            nWaiting++;
            /*
             * finish condition:
             * there is no available task in the work pool and no worker
             * is active
             */
            if (nWaiting == nThreads) {
                ready = true;
                /* problem is finished, announcing all workers */
                notifyAll();
                return null;
            } else {
                while (!ready && tasks.size() == 0) {
                    try {
                        this.wait();
                    } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                }

                if (ready)
                    /* work is done */
                    return null;

                nWaiting--;

            }
        }
        return tasks.remove();

    }

    /**
     * Function which inserts a task in the work pool
     * @param sp The task which must be introduced
     */
    synchronized void putWork(MRCTask sp) {

        tasks.add(sp);
        /* announcing one of the waiting workers */
        this.notify();

    }

}
```

TestMain.Java

```
public class TestMain {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    int nr_proc = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    WorkPool wp = new WorkPool(nr_proc);
    MRCTask.t = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        wp.putWork(new MRCTask());

    Worker[] wrk = new Worker[nr_proc];

    for(int i = 0; i < nr_proc; i++)
        wrk[i] = new Worker(wp);

    for(int i = 0; i < nr_proc; i++)
        wrk[i].start();

    for(int i = 0; i < nr_proc; i++)
        wrk[i].join();

    System.out.println(MRCTask.t);
}

}

class Worker extends Thread {

WorkPool wp;

public Worker(WorkPool wp) {

    this.wp = wp;

}

void work(MRCTask ps) throws Exception {

    ps.processTask();

}

public void run() {

    while (true) {
        MRCTask ps = wp.getWork();
        if (ps == null)
            break;          
        try {
            work(ps);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

}

}

class MRCTask {

static int t;
public void processTask() {
    t += 5;
}

}
```

When running this code, I normally expect to get 50000 as the answer. That only happens when nr_proc is 1. When nr_proc is 2 or 4(in my case, availableProcessor() returns 4), I get random values, like 49960, 49900, 49995 and sometimes even 50000. 
Could you please tell me what is wrong?
Thanks in advance and sorry for this huge code!
PS: I have tried to modify the function processTask() as it follows:

```
public void processTask() {
    synchronized(this) {
        t += 5;
    }
}
```

but, I still get same problem. I thought having synchronized portions would help, but they don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value `t` is static. So the way you tried to synchronize things, it was doomed to failure. You actually didn't synchronize anything because you have many different `MRCTask` instances (10000 in fact). Each one of them has a separate lock/monitor.
Try changing your code in `MRCTask` to this:

```
private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

public void processTask() {
    synchronized (LOCK) {
        t += 5;
    }

}
```

This is different, now you use a shared lock.
See if you still get unpredictable/random results. You won't.
Previously you were just having a classical race condition.

Comment: I have tried this and it worked! Thank you a lot! But, when would a synchronize(this) actually work?

Comment: It would actually work, if `this` was seen the same by all threads. Here you have many `MRCTask` objects and many `this` values respectively. So for example if `this` was your pool object (you have only 1 pool) that would work just fine too. I make sure I have only 1 `LOCK` object and that's why it works for my version too.

Comment: Thank you! Now I begin to understand a little better the java multithreading features.